# Spring RESTful Web service and bean "request" and "session" scope

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am using the pure example code of simple REST service from the spring guide as a base:
http://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

I have added single Bean configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class Config {

    @Bean
    @Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST)

    public RequestData requestHelper() {
        return new RequestData();
    }     

}
```

Then my modified controller looks as follows:

```
@RestController
public class GreetingController {

    private static final String template = "Hello, %s!";
    private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

    AnnotationConfigApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Config.class);

    @RequestMapping("/greeting")
    public Greeting greeting(@RequestParam(value="name", defaultValue="World") String name) {
        System.out.println(applicationContext.getBean(RequestData.class));

        return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(),
                            String.format(template, name));
    }
}
```

and I am getting

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Scope registered for scope 'session']
```

as the result of calling "/greeting"

I have read some description here:
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html however I am still confused.

they write:
"The request, session, and global session scopes are only available if you use a web-aware Spring ApplicationContext implementation".

Does it mean that "AnnotationConfigApplicationContext" which I am using is not allowed in such case? Am I forced to use some xml configuration instead?

Comment: Why are you loading a new application context?

Comment: `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` is for stand-alone spring applications, in case you need web related scopes and features, you should use `WebApplicationContext ` as mentioned by SotiriosDelimanolis. Also if you just need  an instance of `ApplicationContext` to get beans, you should create that in your class with `main()` not as an instance variable in some controller because you don't want to create ApplicationContext again and again

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The quote

> *web-aware Spring ApplicationContext implementation*

refers to an appropriate subclass of [`WebApplicationContext`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/WebApplicationContext.html). You're instantiating a `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` which is not a subtype of `WebApplicationContext` and which does not register the `SESSION` and `REQUEST` scopes.

It also makes very little sense to create a brand new `ApplicationContext` in your `@RestController`. The `@RestController` object is already a bean within a Spring `WebApplicationContext`. Just add your new request scoped `@Bean` to that context and autowire into your controller.

Comment: Ok thanks, this makes a situation a bit more clear. However I still have some doubts regarding the proper usage (I have just started learning spring). How can I access the automatically instantiated WebApplicationContext? I have tried with Autowired - with no result. Also trying to access the request scoped bean via Autowired in RestController finishes with Exception at application startup.

Comment: @Mikolaj You're presumably using Spring MVC with a `DispatcherServlet`. This `DispatcherServlet` is loading its own `WebApplicationContext` (check your config). That's where you should declare your request scoped bean. You can then autowire it normally into your controller.